# How to call android method from server?

Tags: java, android, methods

I have an android application I build which gets the current location.

I want to call this method from a server, and get the location, instead of using a timer in the application which sends the location to the server.

Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 4):

Basically you can only send a trigger to the device so that it then answers by sending the location to the server. This is based on the [Google Cloud Messaging](http://developer.android.com/google/gcm/gcm.html) service. You will find everything you need there in detail.

Answer (score 1):

Another way for you to do this is by using a TCP socket. The Android application must connect up to the server. As long as the connection is live, the server can push down a message requesting the GPS location. When the application receives the message it needs to decode it and decide what to do. It should see that it wants the GPS location and thus decides to send the GPS location back.

Although, like WarrenFaith answered, Google Cloud Messaging is another way to push down an 'event' to the application. From there the app must push the GPS location to the server.

Comment: true but your solution has quite some disadvantages. Basically that the interrupted connections are pita, the server needs to keep quite some sockets open plus the device can't go into deeper sleep with an open socket. So you are technically right but I would not recommend this solution.

Comment: It has it's draw backs, that's for sure. It's just another option. Note: I up-voted your answer because I do believe it's a better solution.